# Can't access Json key with spaces in gulp internationalization module

Tags: javascript, json, gulp

I'm struggling to make this json work into [gulp-html-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-i18n)

```
"test": [
    {
      "reg1": "Korea",
      "reg2 test": "222",
      "reg3 name": "name2",
    },
    {
      "reg1": "Japan",
      "reg2 test": "223",
      "reg3 name": "name3",
    }
  ],
```

In HTML I'm doing

```
${{filename.test.0.reg1}}$
```

And it works, but when I try any of the following alternatives, none worked. Is there a way to accomplish this without changing the json?

```
${{filename.test.0.reg2 test}}$
${{filename.test.0.['reg2 test']}}$
${{filename.test.0.[reg2 test]}}$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `gulp-html-i18n` uses a simple regex-based engine in order to replace `${{ }}$` placeholders with the strings you define in your JSON.

The regex used to identify placeholders is the following:

```
/\${{ ?([\w-.]+) ?}}\$/g
```

[[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/qV2jO2/1)]

As you can see this only permits a single leading/trailing space in the placeholder. The leading/trailing space is not interpreted as part of the property key.

If you want spaces **within** a property key you need a different regex. The following regex allows you to use spaces in properties. Leading/trailing spaces are still ignored and not interpreted as part of the property key:

```
/\${{ ?([\w-. ]+?) ?}}\$/
```

[[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/nH1eM5/1)]

You can tell `gulp-html-i18n` to use this regex with the [`langRegExp` option](https://github.com/webyom/gulp-html-i18n#options):

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(i18n({
      langDir: './lang',
      langRegExp: /\${{ ?([\w-. ]+?) ?}}\$/g
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Then in your HTML you can use placeholders like this:

```
${{filename.test.0.reg2 test}}$
${{ filename.test.0.reg2 test }}$
${{filename.test.0.reg1}}$
${{ filename.test.0.reg1 }}$
```

Which should produce the following output:

```
222
222
Korea
Korea
```

Comment: Great answer! thank you very much. By any chance, do you know how can I get integers from the json translations file? Now I'm only getting strings.

Comment: You can't, [strings only](https://github.com/webyom/gulp-html-i18n/blob/3597969/lib/index.js#L71), at least with the default `"regex"` engine. You can try `renderEngine: "mustache"` which will use [mustache templates](https://github.com/mustache/mustache). The placeholder syntax will be different however.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use square brackets `[]` to access keys with spaces. When you are using so, you need not use `.`. So it can be written as

```
${{filename.test[0]['reg2 test']}}$
```

**Example**

```
> a=[{test:"hello"},{"test str":"world"}]
> a[1]["test str"]
"world"
```

Comment: I'm afraid this notation does not worked with the  i18n module that I'm using.